# Excel VBA Debugging

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running into a "run time error 1004".  I suspect this has something to do with how much data I want my code to process.  Currently I am running a 246 column by 30,000 row.  What I'm trying to achieve is to consolidate my data into one row item because the current system export the data into individual row as a duplicate for certain data columns.  As a result, the data has a ladder/stagger effect where there's duplicate row ID with blank cells in one and data below it.

Example:

[image]

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub consolidate()

    Const SHEET_NAME = "Archer Search Report"
    Const NO_OF_COLS = 101

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim irow As Long, iLastRow As Long, c As Long, count As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    iLastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' scan up sheet
    For irow = iLastRow - 1 To 2 Step -1

         ' if same id below
        If ws.Cells(irow + 1, 1) = ws.Cells(irow, 1) Then

            ' scan across
            For c = 1 To NO_OF_COLS
                ' if blank copy from below
                If Len(ws.Cells(irow, c)) = 0 Then
                   ws.Cells(irow, c) = ws.Cells(irow + 1, c)
                End If
            Next

            ws.Rows(irow + 1).Delete
            count = count + 1

        End If

    Next

    MsgBox iLastRow - 1 & " rows scanned" & vbCr & _
           count & " rows deleted from " & ws.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

I suspect it has to do with the massive amount of data it's running and wanted to see if that is the case.  If so, is there an alternative approach?  Appreciate the assistance.

Note: I got this awesome code from someone(CDP1802)here and have been using it for years with smaller data set.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: It's unlikely to be due to having more data.  Any chance you have error values in your worksheet?

Comment: @TimWilliams I thought about that too. But when I tested it, error 13 was raised for type mismatch. I guess We have to wait for the exact line that's causing the error. The code is running well on my computer

Comment: Do you have any event triggered code?

Comment: @TimWilliams there's no error values in my worksheet as they're all raw text data.  The error line appears to be pointed here: 'ws.Cells(irow, c) = ws.Cells(irow + 1, c)'.  for "If blank copy from below".

Comment: @SuperSymmetry I do not have event triggered code.

Comment: Is your sheet protected? forgive me for the question, but this is a puzzler

Comment: What are the values of `iRow` and `c` when it fails, and what values are in those respective cells?

Comment: @SuperSymmetry not protected. No worries.  I can't seem to figure out what's wrong either.

Comment: @TimWilliams the values for irow and c should just be a text value either numerical or a string.

Comment: Well your code "should just" work, but clearly something specific is not right there...

Comment: @TimWilliams it normally does.  I typically use it for other reports.  Only this one throws an error.  I had assumed its due to the massive amount of data, so I reduced the number of column from 244 to 100, then to 60 and it finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach which does not require sorting by id,  includes some checking for error values, and does not overwrite any data in the output.

```
Sub consolidate()

    Const SHEET_NAME = "Archer Search Report"
    Const NO_OF_COLS = 10 'for example

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, dataIn, dataOut
    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Dim dict As Object, id, rwOut As Long, idRow As Long, vIn, vOut, rngData As Range
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
   
    Set rngData = ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, NO_OF_COLS)
    dataIn = rngData.Value  'input data as 2D array
    
    ReDim dataOut(1 To UBound(dataIn, 1), 1 To NO_OF_COLS) 'resize "out" to match "in" array size
    rwOut = 0               'row counter for "out" array
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataIn, 1)
        
        id = dataIn(i, 1) 'id for this "row"
        
        If Not dict.exists(id) Then
            'not seen this id before
            rwOut = rwOut + 1
            dict(id) = rwOut       'add id and row to dictionary
            dataOut(rwOut, 1) = id 'add id to "out" array
        End If
        
        idRow = dict(id)          'row locator in the "out" array
        For c = 2 To NO_OF_COLS
            vIn = dataIn(i, c)        'incoming value
            vOut = dataOut(idRow, c)  'existing value
            'ignore error values, and don't overwrite any existing value in the "out" array
            If Not IsError(vIn) Then
                If Len(vIn) > 0 And Len(vOut) = 0 Then dataOut(idRow, c) = vIn
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
    
    rngData.Value = dataOut 'replace input data with output array

    MsgBox "Got " & rwOut & " unique rows from " & UBound(dataIn, 1)

End Sub
```

Comment: This code works!!! And it processed much faster then the current one.  I'm still trying to understand it and may have questions afterwards.